# TCP performance tuning with one server receiving data from multiple clients

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have multiple clients sending data to a single server through tcp socket, all the clients and server are running on linux(CentOS 7.2) servers with a 10 gb network interface.

But I found that the performance is much slower than a single client and a single server.

So I did another test with iperf, a network bandwidth measurement tool.

First start a server on server217, then use a single client(server218) to test the bandwidth, here is the result :

[image]

and the client side output:

[image]

then I use two clients(server218 and server219) to start the test at the same time, and the result is:

[image]

and the client side output:

[image]

**As you can see, when I use two clients, the result is 【3.08 + 4.04 = 7.12 Gb】，which is much slower than the previous 【9.41 Gb】, besides, the bandwidth also becomes very unstable.**

I tried to set a bigger tcp buffer but get no difference.

The original tcp buffer is

```
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem: 4096    87380   6291456
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem: 4096    16384   4194304
```

I changed to

```
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem: 4096    87380   8388608
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem: 4096    65536   8388608
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the `nice` value for the server process, giving a higher priority amongst userspace programs and see if things are slightly better

Comment: @Scab，I just tried, but it's all the same. I tested with/without max nice value both for 3 times, and the average result is 7.5 gb/s with max nice value and 7.6 without max nice value.

Comment: niceness should be minimized not maximized, try with -20 for example.